# how can we generate codecov file in python locally

Tags: python, codecov

I want to generate codecov in python locally. i know we can generate codecov on github using codecov action. but want to know how to do  that in local system. can you have any reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible. But if you just want to measure your code coverage, you can use for example [Coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.0.3/).